# Trying to create a flex box container but it wont create the box and displays the text

Tags: flexbox

Sorry for the noob question I'm trying to create a flex box with in my flex box but it wont create the box and just displays the

```
<div>
<div> class="flex-box-container-1" </div>
<div> id="flex-box-result</div>
</div>
```

Theres the code in question then below is what that results in;

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You forgot " closing at flex-box-result and the id definition is not inside div declaration